# Is there a way to solve an equation without a root?

Tags: r, solver, non-linear-regression

at the moment I am writing my bachelor thesis and I have to program in R for the first time. I think not the best way to learn R but never mind.

My question is concerning a function that can solve an equation like this:

```
q <- function(ytc) {
  (5 / ((1 + (ytc / 4))^4 * ((1645 * 5 / 1826) - (1640 * 5 / 1826)))) + 
    (5 / ((1 + (ytc / 4))^4 * ((1736 * 5 / 1826) - (1640 * 5 / 1826)))) + 
    (5 / ((1 + (ytc / 4))^4 * ((1826 * 5 / 1826) - (1640 * 5 / 1826)))) + 
    100 / (((1 + (ytc / 4))^4 * ((1826 * 5 / 1826) - (1640 * 5 / 1826)))) - 100
}
```

My aim is to simply solve for the ytc what should be the yield to call of a bond. But I cannot find any way to figure it out. This should be a simple PV calculation like: PV=c/(1+r/4)^4*t1+c/(1+r/4)^4*t2+.... and hence solve vor r. But don't know how to do that. I tried several functions like uniroot, unroot.all, ... but nothing could figure out the solution. Additionally a real problem is that in the my main equation I am discounting 20 payments and and I was not able to modify it as a linear equation yet due to missing knowledge about what to to with the exponents.

I hope anyone could help me.

Looking forward to hear from anyone.

Comment: Just to clarify: The function I wrote is of the form c/(1+r/4)^4*t-PV=0 as i tried uniroot etc. which yielded no solutions.

Comment: You say you have an equation `c/(1+r/4)^4*t-PV=0`.  What is PV? Is it a constant, or variable, or  a product of two variables P and V, or something else?  You should solve this equation with respect to what variable: c, v , r , PV ?

Comment: Remember, we know the R language, and some of us know mathematics, but we have zero knowledge of the problem you are trying to solve. We don't know what each variable means, what ytc (or any other acronym) means, what do you want to discover, where are acronyms and where are products of variables, or anything else.  We don't want to guess, either.

Comment: @user31264 I am really sorry for the inconvenience! It is my first post this is why I am not that accurate in expressing my problem. :/ you can imagine the equation as follows: it is a simple equation of the form y=c/(1+x/4)^4*t where everything is known except for x which I want to solve for. This means that ytc=x.

Comment: Is it `c/((1+x/4)^4)*t` , or is it `c/(1+x/4)^(4*t) ` ?

Comment: It is meant to be c/(1+(x/4))^(4*t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not quite understand why you cannot solve your equation.

Take your function `q`:

```
q <- function(ytc) {
  (5 / ((1 + (ytc / 4))^4 * ((1645 * 5 / 1826) - (1640 * 5 / 1826)))) + 
  (5 / ((1 + (ytc / 4))^4 * ((1736 * 5 / 1826) - (1640 * 5 / 1826)))) + 
  (5 / ((1 + (ytc / 4))^4 * ((1826 * 5 / 1826) - (1640 * 5 / 1826)))) + 
  100 / (((1 + (ytc / 4))^4 * ((1826 * 5 / 1826) - (1640 * 5 / 1826)))) - 100
}
```

and assuming you want to find the value of `ytc` for which function `q` is zero then you can use `uniroot` as follows:

```
uniroot(q, c(0,10))
```

and if you want a more accurate solution use

```
uniroot(q, c(0,10),tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)
```

Seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is buggy, because operator^ (exponentiation) takes a precedence over operator* (multiplication).  `foo^4*bar` means (in virtually any programming language where `^` means exponentiation) "calculate foo^4 and then multiply the result by bar".  You need (I removed extra brackets):

```
q <- function(ytc) {
  5 / (1 + ytc / 4) ^ (4 * (1645 * 5 / 1826 - 1640 * 5 / 1826)) + 
  5 / (1 + ytc / 4) ^ (4 * (1736 * 5 / 1826 - 1640 * 5 / 1826)) + 
  5 / (1 + ytc / 4) ^ (4 * (1826 * 5 / 1826 - 1640 * 5 / 1826)) + 
  100 / (1 + ytc / 4) ^ (4 * (1826 * 5 / 1826 - 1640 * 5 / 1826))
  - 100
}
```

or much better:

```
x1 = 1645 * 5 / 1826 - 1640 * 5 / 1826
x2 = 1736 * 5 / 1826 - 1640 * 5 / 1826
x3 = 1826 * 5 / 1826 - 1640 * 5 / 1826
q <- function(ytc) {
    a = 1 + ytc / 4
    5 / a ** (4 * x1) + 5 / a ** (4 * x2) + 5 / a ** (4 * x3)
    + 100 / a ** (4 * x3)  - 100
}
```

Remember, as a newbie, if you will write complicated multi-line expression with huge number of nested brackets, you will almost always make a mistake.  Avoid them like a plague!  Divide them to comprehensible expressions.

Comment: It seems as if the results are not quite accurate. At least to my purpose. Is there maybe another function I could use to solve for a value?